# How to Search for data in Firebase android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an algorithm looking for Firebase data but it doesn't work and records an error to me, I want to register into Edittext Value and it will bring me the appropriate card
I use the recylerView

```
recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
getmRootFLY = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FLY");
list = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,list);
recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
getmRootFLY.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren())
        {
            Fly fly = dataSnapshot.getValue(Fly.class);
            list.add(fly);
        }
        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("First Name");
mRootRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String name = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
        TextView myLoginTextFromDB = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello_name_from_db);
        myLoginTextFromDB.setText(name);

    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
    }
});
EditText editTextTextPersonName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
editTextTextPersonName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        Query query = databaseReference.child("FLY").equalTo(editable.toString());
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                {
                    list.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dss: snapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        final Fly fly = dss.getValue(Fly.class);
                        list.add(fly);
                    }
                    MyAdapter myAdapter1 = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),list);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter1);
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

It is important to note Getmrootfly adds the card to the array and basically shows me the data available in Firebase

And all code that appears as an edittexttexteonname is a code that needs to look for the data

[image]

Comment: What part of the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do? More specifically: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: EditText editTextTextPersonName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
editTextTextPersonName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {....................................              From the part of Edittext to the end below

Comment: What specific behavior did you expect to happen when you debugged that line, and what happened instead? Did you check all the values? Also: "records an error to me". Please edit your question to include the exact error message and stack trace. --- At this point I'd also recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there makes it a lot more likely that someone here can help.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.